# Flutter Showing two horizontal lines either side of a text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show two horizontal lines either side of text: Or . As shown in the image below:

[image]

I have tried to do this using a Row with two dividers and a text in it. However it is only showing the Text("Or"), on the screen.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
Widget showDivider() {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Divider(
        indent: 10,
        endIndent: 10,
        thickness: 5.0,
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
      Text('or'),
      Divider(
        indent: 10,
        endIndent: 10,
        thickness: 5.0,
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

No matter which settings I try on the Dividers they are not showing.

Any help in getting this sorted would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your Both **Dividers** with **Expanded**.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both the dividers with expanded widgets

```dart
Widget showDivider() {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
     Expanded(
      child: Divider(
        indent: 10,
        endIndent: 10,
        thickness: 5.0,
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
      )
      Text('or'),
      Expanded(
        child: Divider(
        indent: 10,
        endIndent: 10,
        thickness: 5.0,
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
     ).
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Expanded` Widgets

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Divider(
                indent: 10,
                endIndent: 10,
                thickness: 5.0,
                height: 5.0,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ),

            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Text(
                'or',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),

            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Divider(
                indent: 10,
                endIndent: 10,
                thickness: 5.0,
                height: 5.0,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  height: .3,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
            Text('or'),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  height: .3,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]